# (How) can I recover lost whistle register? [Male]

Tags: voice

**Disclaimer:** I have never taken proper singing classes so my vocabulary may be incorrect, I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks to my quite late voice change (when I was ~15) I have have developed a taste for high-pitched singing.
Before the voice change, my range was about A3-F6~A6 depending on training.
Later I kind of grew into a baritone voice (not exactly sure about that) which went from G2-G4, and a falsetto/whistle that was quite airy and could still reach A3-F#6.

At first I wasn't able to get a mixed voice, so I could either sing ~soprano or baritone (not very practical for most classical rock). With some practice I was able to get to this mixed voice to have a stronger upper range from G4 to B5 (sounds more Rob Halford than Axl Rose unfortunately, but working on it).

After screaming a bit too much during a party and getting sick two years ago (was 20 at the time), I lost my voice for a few days. When I recovered, I could not use the whistle/falsetto register with the same technique I had always used, it either 'fell back' to mixed chest up to B5, or simply made no sound as if the voice were broken. With time, I was able to use the falsetto voice again if I sung softly around the 4th octave, but to this day I'm unable to use this voice for singing very high notes.

Is there anything I can do to recover whistle register?
I'd be elated if I could sing the end of [Aerosmith's Crazy](https://youtu.be/NMNgbISmF4I?t=5m11s) again, would that be possible?

Comment: Probably not.  Once your vocal cords go thru puberty,  they won't go back.   You should work with a trained voice coach to make sure you don't attempt something that will cause permanent damage to your existing range.

Comment: Its seems weird since two years ago I had long gone through puberty, and could still do this falsetto!

Comment: Well, hormones continue to change body parts thru at least age 25.  Or it may be that there was minor damage from screaming and illness that's limited your vocal cords' flexibility.

Comment: If it were the latter that caused my loss, would there be anything to recover?

Answer (score 1):

First,  high range isn't necessarily whistle register.  Whistle register literally sounds like you're whistling (Minnie Ripperton uses it in "Loving you",  Mariah Carey used it, albeit a harsher sounding R&B style version of it).   That and although males CAN sing in whistle register, it's REALLY RARE -  Brett Manning sings in it and can teach it too )

I think you're referring to headvoice which is how most people sing high.  That said, it sounds like you may have temporarily damaged (?) your vocal chords by screaming.
(The question mark is there because I'm not an ENT so I can't  say this for fact, but the fact you didn't mention any nagging hoarsness or loss of speaking voice hints at it.)

That said,  all voices change with age (especially puberty), the good news is  you can recover some of it, maybe even all of your range.  I'm a second bass and can sing from "F#" one octave over middle "C" down to the lowest "C" on the piano, but I've had years of training and have had to rebuild my voice from scratch due to exploratory surgery that cut my diaphragm muscle.   I don't go as high as I  used to, but I'm slowly building back up to it.  Look into voice lessons with a good coach !