# Can I lose the ability to sing whistle notes?

Tags: theory, voice, vocal-range

I am a male 14 years old and I can whistle quite well, but if my voice will change will I lose the ability to reach them? And high notes in particular??

Comment: Related question: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/71822/how-can-i-recover-lost-whistle-register-male

Comment: As comments below mention, do you mean true whistling, where sound is generated in the oral cavity with tongue and lip positions, or do you mean  singing in  falsetto?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why you should not be able to whistle well after your voice breaks. The voice is produced in your throat. You don't whistle from your throat, it's only the air that comes from there. The whistle is produced from your lips, which won't have much effect on the depth of your voice.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about the "[whistle register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistle_register)".

Comment: @Aaron - you could be right - it's lost something in translation...

Comment: @Aaron My thanks to you for introducing me to that bit of vocab!  I never knew there was anything above "falsetto."